# serializer being called multiple times django python

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

This is code of serializer which is working perfectly fine..
But,serializer is being called multiple times

```
class StatisticLocationSerializer(serializers.one, two):
      domains = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
      statistic = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
      patents = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
      inventors = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

#### METHOD FIELDS ####
      def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
            return something


class Meta:
    model = models.LocationModel
    fields = ( 'domains', 'statistic',
              'patents')
    lookup_field = 'slug'
    extra_kwargs = {
        'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
    }

##### THIS IS HOW I"M CALLING SERIALIZER CLASS ####
serializer_class = StatisticLocationSerializer
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = self.get_serializer_class().setup_eager_loading(queryset)
```

NOTE: I CHECKED THE FUCTION get_queryset is also being called only Once

Comment: Maybe you can specify what "being called means"? Like getting intialized multiple times? Maybe you can tell how often? If you would use it as you show it inside a view set it would probably at least get initialized two times as the view set would initialize it....

Comment: what are you using `viewset` or `genericApiView` or any thing, please mention. One of the possible case, get_serializer_class actually called the serializer that should not be called ( view function's responsibility is to do that ).

Comment: I'm using model viewset ...it is getting intialized by three times..

Comment: is it same as the number of records returned by the queryset? then it might be something related to how ListSerializer is implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sending a request to your endpoint through the DRF user interface? I had the same problem with functions being called twice or thrice (**init** functions) with no explanation.

However, if you send a request to your endpoint via a service like Postman, the functions are being called once. So, it seems to be a problem with the DRF's own interface rather than the code itself.

For real world uses, your code should be fine.